# Compare npm pack tarball with what's on NPM

Tags: npm, zip, diff, tar, archive

I made some changes to an NPM project and can't remember if I included them in the latest NPM tarball that I published. The git history is kind of independent of what I publish sometimes.

Is there some way to compare the file differences between what's on NPM and a tarballed version of my current project?

It would be nice to be able to do a diff on all the files and see what the differences are, anyone know a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare two Zip-balls with the open-source tool **comp_zip** available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unzip-ada/).

Comment: Only a command line output so far, with details and a summary which tells how many files are different, and how many files are missing in the other archive. Which system are you using?

Comment: I want to run this on both macos and linux

Comment: Both are supported (among others)

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm module [npm-package-diff](https://github.com/sergcen/npm-package-diff), here example

`npx pkdiff react@16.12.0 16.11.0`

`npx pkdiff react 16.11.0` or compare with latest

`npx pkdiff <new-version> <old-version>`